# Impossible to set the Cloud Firebase daily spending limit

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I just purchased a Firebase blaze plan (unlimited) but I tried to setup the daily quota as suggested in their documentation:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#set_spending_limits

[image]

The problem is that I can't find this option on my own console, there is no "Set budget" section:
[image]
[image]

I really need to setup this daily alert to avoid any bad surprises.
Why am I not seeing this option? Thanks

Comment: Maybe this one helps, but you have to implement it yourself ... https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/notify#cap_disable_billing_to_stop_usage

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well it seems they removed the possibility...

The documentation page (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#set_spending_limits) has been updated and they explained:

> Important: Cloud Firestore no longer supports new App Engine spending limits. After December 12, 2019, you cannot apply new App Engine spending limits. Spending limits set before December 12 still apply.

Now there is only the monthly budget left to use.

The budget on the Firebase Blaze plan is unlimited and there is not a single way to supervize it on a daily basis...

Comment: This is a dark pattern.

Answer (score 1):

If available the <kbd>Daily spending limit</kbd> shows right at the top of the page, as you can see in this screenshot I just took of one of my projects:

[image]

Since this doesn't show up for you, you might want to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

In the meantime, the closest you can get is by [setting up billing alerts](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/notify#cap_disable_billing_to_stop_usage) and then disabling (billing on) the project. While this is not a hard cap, and more work, it should allow you to get pretty close.