# Does Firestore have an api that allows me to check daily reads/writes so I know when I'm over a certain amount?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I know that I could implement a counter in my application but using an api would still be a cleaner solution - if one exists?

Basically, Firestore has Spark free tier limits (think 50,000 reads/day) that I don't want to exceed. So whenever my app was going to do firestore reads, I would like a way to simply ask firestore whether I'm over a certain number.

I'm also reading that Google intentionally got rid of Firebase spending limits.. which seems really sketchy... [Impossible to set the Cloud Firebase daily spending limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60040973/impossible-to-set-the-cloud-firebase-daily-spending-limit/60229882#60229882)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such API as part of Firebase. The ways to monitor usage are documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/monitor-usage), but none of them is an API.

You might be able to get some data through the [Cloud Monitoring API](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/docs). But this API isn't made for client-side access though, so you'll have to wrap it yourself.

A final alternative would be to look at a service like https://firerun.io/ who automate a lot of this.

Comment: can you provide a bit more detail? what are cloud apis and are they different from normal apis?

Comment: I provided a link to the most likely candidate. I recommend reading a bit there, trying it (for example in the built-in API explorer), and then making up your mind on whether you want to go that route (hint: you most likely won't).